# Duplicate input on click, insert before clicked element - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone

I have markup like so:

```js
$('label.duplicate').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var _for = $(this).attr('for');
    
        $('input[name="' + _for + '"]').clone().insertBefore($(this));
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="input_one[]">
    <label class="duplicate" for="input_one[]">Add another car</label>
```

This doesn't duplicate, or provide an error so I don't know why this is not working?

Comment: its working ...

Comment: your code already working good

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure whats blocking it my end - I see it working on here. Bizzare.

Comment: is the label generated dynamically? That might be the problem if the on click listener executes prior to appending the label in the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working, but you need to wait for the dom-structur to load before you run you code. Put everything inside documet.ready like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('label.duplicate').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var _for = $(this).attr('for');

    $('input[name="' + _for + '"]').clone().insertBefore($(this));
  });
})
```

Or insert your code dead last on you page. Read more about this here: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Yeah, after the edits I see it working on here. I have it run in a document ready.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="input_one[]">
<label class="duplicate" for="input_one[]">Add another car</label>
```

just `.duplicate` is enough to duplicate:

```
$(function(){ 
$('.duplicate').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var _for = $(this).attr('for');

    $('input[name="' + _for + '"]').clone().insertBefore($(this));
  });
}
```